# sql copying duplicates

Tags: sql, replication, sybase

I'm trying to fill 'Col4' null values with the values above using 'Col1' and 'Col3'. Here is a brief explanation of the columns:

Col1 - User Entry date

Col2 - Calendar date

Col3 - Difference between the dates in Col1

Col4 - Entry amount

What the data currently looks like:

```
 |   Col1          |   Col2          |   Col3       |   Col4
 |   2016-01-01    |   2016-01-01    |   3          |   $10
 |   null          |   2016-01-02    |   null       |   null
 |   null          |   2016-01-03    |   null       |   null
 |   2016-01-04    |   2016-01-04    |   1          |   $2
 |   2016-01-05    |   2016-01-05    |   2          |   $7
 |   null          |   2016-01-06    |   null       |   null
 |   2016-01-07    |   2016-01-07    |   3          |   $5
 |   null          |   2016-01-08    |   null       |   null
 |   null          |   2016-01-09    |   null       |   null
```

Expected Results:

```
 |   Col1          |   Col2          |   Col3       |   Col4
 |   2016-01-01    |   2016-01-01    |   3          |   $10
 |   null          |   2016-01-02    |   null       |   $10
 |   null          |   2016-01-03    |   null       |   $10
 |   2016-01-04    |   2016-01-04    |   1          |   $2
 |   2016-01-05    |   2016-01-05    |   2          |   $7
 |   null          |   2016-01-06    |   null       |   $7
 |   2016-01-07    |   2016-01-07    |   3          |   $5
 |   null          |   2016-01-08    |   null       |   $5
 |   null          |   2016-01-09    |   null       |   $5
```

The formula works by counting the number in Col3 and then copying the corresponding amount in Col4 to the rows below. Col3 defines how many rows below (including its own row).

I'm currently using Sybase. I don't have any ideas on how I can do this. Any help would be appreciated thanks. 
Note: this is a sample of data and the dates go from 2000 - 2016

Comment: What's the query for your current result set or are those rows in a table?

Comment: Those are the rows in a table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server By given sample data we can achieve the above result Set by using CTE

Sample Data :

```
declarE  @Table1 TABLE 
    (Col1 varchar(10), Col2 varchar(10), Col3 varchar(4), Col4 varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)
VALUES
    ('2016-01-01', '2016-01-01', '3', '$10'),
    (NULL, '2016-01-02', NULL, NULL),
    (NULL, '2016-01-03', NULL, NULL),
    ('2016-01-04', '2016-01-04', '1', '$2'),
    ('2016-01-05', '2016-01-05', '2', '$7'),
    (NULL, '2016-01-06', NULL, NULL),
    ('2016-01-07', '2016-01-07', '3', '$5'),
    (NULL, '2016-01-08', NULL, NULL),
    (NULL, '2016-01-09', NULL, NULL)
;
```

Script :

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT T1.Col1, 
                T1.Col2,
                T1.Col3, 

                Col4 = COALESCE(T1.Col4, (SELECT TOP 1 Col4 
                                      FROM   @Table1 T2 
                                      WHERE  T2.Col2 < T1.Col2
                                             AND Col4 IS NOT NULL 
                                      ORDER  BY Col2 DESC)) 
         FROM   @Table1 T1) 
UPDATE T 
SET    
       T.Col4 = C.Col4 
FROM   @Table1 T 
       INNER JOIN cte C 
               ON T.col2 = C.col2 
WHERE  T.col1 IS NULL 
        OR T.col2 IS NULL 
        OR T.col3 IS NULL 

        Select * from @Table1
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help! Unfortunately, this sybase version does not support `with`

Comment: I've solved it myself. Your script hinted me towards to answer thanks!

Comment: @henry91 I have no idea to how to write in Sybase but all the RDBMS concepts quite similar in logic so I thought to give it a shot. It helped you in to move towards in your script ..Great work